# Java: Make Enum tie to a different String value

Tags: java, enums

So I have something like this

```
public enum DataType {

    RECORD_TYPE("0"),
    ...

    private String code;

    private DataType(String code){
         this.code = code;
    }

    public String getCode() {
         return code;
    }
}
```

So when I do

```
System.out.println(DataType.RECORD_TYPE);
```

It prints out string `RECORD_TYPE`, but I want to it to print out `0`, and I dont want to do this

```
System.out.println(DataType.RECORD_TYPE.getCode());
```

as I feel that the user will most likely forget to put the `getCode()` in. I know Enum does not have `toString` method, is there a way for me to change the default behavior when java convert Enum to String?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I know Enum does not have toString method

It actually does have [a toString method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#toString%28%29) like any `Object`s and you can override it.

Answer (score 3):

Sure.  Override the `toString()` function.

```
public String toString() {
  return code;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add this toString() method to your enum

```
public String toString() {
    return getCode();
}
```